# Class & Functionality Selective Generics

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, generics

I have an interface called `IFilterDataSourceAdapter`. This interface exposes EndPoints for adapting to an incoming data source (`IEnumrable<T>`, `iCollectionView` or `DataTable` or `DataView` or `XmlDocument`) and provides functionality to filter them intuitively.

1. It accepts the names of the fields from the datasource .
2. Produces a list of `FilterFields` each exposing three properties

   1. Name of the field
   2. Filter Operator list based on the `Type` of the field - Equals, Contains, Less Than etc.
   3. Supplied value field.

   GUI can use this `FilterField` list to display filter panel.
3. The adapter would supply its own `ICommand` to execute filter call from the GUI.

So in thw adapter, I want to do following

1. If the incoming datasource is of type `IEnumrable<SomeClass>` I would produce `AsQueryable()` **Linq Expressions** when a filter is applied and expose the **queried `IEnumrable<SomeClass>`** list back.
2. If the incoming datasource is of type `ICollectionView` I would produce `Filter` delegate and refresh the collection view.
3. If the incoming datasource is of type `DataTable` or `DataView` I would produce `DataFilter` string based query and refresh the data table or the data view.
4. If the incoming datasource is of type `XDocument` it would produce `XPath` expressions and list of `XElements` filtered.

I want to do this based on `Generics` constrained to the above types of data sources and also distinguish between the `Filter` command execution accordingly.

Can we have a single interface `IFilterDataSourceAdapter<T>` be constrained for its members (fields and functions) based on the T being either `IEnurable<SomeClass>` or `ICollectionView` or `DataTable` or `DataView` or `XDocument`?

**EDIT:**

My current implementation is actually 5 types of asbtract adapters for each type of datasource and they are working fine.  They all implement `IFilterDataSourceAdapter`. But I think may be we can make `IFilterDataSourceAdapter<T>` with constrains than can be more suited to each adapter implementation design wise. So may be what I have is already fine.

May be I am overthinking on things!!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an answer but too long for a comment... Based on my understanding of your question, I would say what you have now (common base interface with different interfaces each specific to a data source) is fine.

I'm referring specifically to this part of your question:

> Can we have a single interface `IFilterDataSourceAdapter<T>` be
>   constrained for its members (fields and functions) based on the T
>   being either `IEnurable<SomeClass>` or `ICollectionView` or `DataTable` or
>   `DataView` or `XDocument`?

If your "generic" interface should specify different implementation based on the type of its generic parameter T, then the interface is not actually generic, is it?

With generics you should be abstracting away behaviors that are common to different types, and constraints should only allow you to define more precisely the set of different types you're defining this common behavior for.